# AJAX: добиться эффекта require из PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Как добиться эффекта, аналогичному

```
require `content.php`;
```

с помощью AJAX? Данная задача актуальна, например, при создании вкладок.

В `content.php` находится, большей частью, html-код, ну может быть с небольшим добавлением php-кода. Конечно, можно весь HTML-код запихнуть в `echo` (во всех примерах AJAX, что я видел, так и делалось), но тогда теряется подцветка HTML-синтаксиса, что недопустимо.

Comment: Может быть, прекратить использовать HTML код в `.php` файлах и перейти на шаблонизаторы ? Начните с `Twig`

Comment: Спасибо Вам за совет, но всё же?

Comment: а что не так с загрузкой такого файла по ajax?

Comment: Зачем вам нужно echo? Что вам мешает выводить разметку как обычно?

Comment: Хорошо, покажите пожалуйста пример вывода разметки через AJAX, которая находится в PHP-файле.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. Метод `load()` библиотеки `jQuery` (а без неё использование AJAX довольно громоздкое) позволяет загрузить содержимое файла внутрь указанного тэга.

```
$('#container').load('content/content.php');
```

Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=1390).

Answer (score 2):

Для начала стоит разделить весь проект на 2 части.
1 - Серверная часть (backend) 
2 - Клиентская часть (frontend)

Если пользователь уже открыл страницу, серверная часть уже закончила свою работу и теперь только клиентская часть может работать дальше. Ничто не мешает клиентской части обращаться к серверной с помощью AJAX. 
Из вопроса не совсем понятно, какого результата необходимо добиться. Подозреваю, что есть php файл, который должен вернуть HTML страницу, которую, в свою очередь клиент получит посредством AJAX.

Для подсветки синтаксиса со вставками PHP кода не нужно хранить весь HTML в переменных или строках, лучше использовать вставки или шаблонизатор. Ниже небольшой пример работы с шаблонами без шаблонизатора.

```html
<?php
$title = 'Заголовок страницы';
$body = 'Тело страницы';
$list = [1=>'Первый',2=>'Второй',3=>'Третий'];
?>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1><?=$title?></h1>
    <p><?=$body?></p>
    <select name="select">
      <?php foreach ($list as $value=>$title):?>
        <option value="<?=$value?>"><?=$title?></option>
      <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>
  </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. Я задал этот вопрос, выполняя создание вкладок, когда при переключении на другую вкладку её содержимое нужно было подгрузить через AJAX. У меня был только один элементарный пример, где простое содержимое вкладок хранилось в аргументах 'echo' php-файла. Естественно, для практики такой способ не подходит - нужна по меньшей мере подсветка синтаксиса, каковой нет в аргументах функций.